# Chat in mobile app isn’t logged in

Tags: support, chat, ios-app, mobile-app

When I click the button to open Chat in the mobile app on my iPhone, the Safari page that loads within the app isn’t logged in, even though I am logged in to Chat in the actual browser and am logged in inside of the app. This makes the Chat interface in the app pointless, as it is harder to use than just opening Safari because it isn’t logged in by default.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7
- OS Version: Version 12.2 (Build 16E227)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log in in the browser hosted within the app once, it should persist for future chat visits.

We're not doing any new development on the mobile apps at the moment, so that's your best bet.